# GreaseMonkey only adds custom click function to first element

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

I have a page with a bunch of tables that all share a class.  I'd like to be able to add a click function to each of them using GreaseMonkey.  The script runs but only the first table ever seems to work.  Clicking on it causes a message to be logged, the others do nothing.

Here's my GreaseMonkey script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.data').click( function() {
            console.log( "clicked" );
            return false;
    });
});
```

Sample HTML:

```
<div>
    <table class="data" id="125232">
        ...
    </table>
    <table class="data" id="252123">
        ...
    <table>
    <table class="data" id="125234">
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

So in this case, only the table with id 125232 has a working click function.

Comment: Are those tables are created during run time.?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/H2anD/).

Comment: There is definitely some content loading that occurs on that page but I can't tell if the tables themselves are being created dynamically.  Do you have a suggestion for a fix assuming they are?

Comment: vcsjones, I probably should have said I'm aware of that.  I pasted this directly into the console and it works.  It's only a problem when working with GreaseMonkey.

Answer (score 4):

Use delegated events: ([jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/))

```
$('body').on('click', 'table.data', function(e){
    console.log('Clicked!');
});
```

Comment: This appears to be working how I expect!  Thank you very much!  I don't have enough rep to upvote, but hopefully others can help me out in that front.

Comment: delegated events don't get enough press coverage.  jQuery kind of makes it hard to understand what they really do -- but they are WONDERFUL.